# Weblogic JDBC Connections: multi-statement init SQL

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, datasource

When setting up a data source in WLS we can give it an *init SQL* statement, which is executed immediately after creation of every connection for this data source.

So far we are using..

```
SQL ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=user01
```

.. as we are logging in using an application `user02` which has less rights than the owner `user01`, but we still want the data source to see the schema.

Now we'd like to add some session meta information to the DS connections, for debugging purposes on the DB side. The statements..

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info('bar');
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module('qux', 'garp');
```

.. allow you to set custom strings as identifiers, which will then show up in colums of `V_$SESSION`, thus giving the DBA some more information about a DB connection.

**My problem**
How is it possible to have multi-line init SQL statements? Note that the init SQL syntax expects an SQL command which is preceded by `SQL` and which does not end in a semicolon `;`.

---

*Edit:

What I tried so far is something along the lines of..*

```
begin
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=uzms01';
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info('bar');
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module('qux', 'garp');
end;
```

*.. but I keep getting errors.* :(

Comment: For setting the current [schema](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setSchema-java.lang.String-) (or maybe [catalog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog-java.lang.String-)), you should use the JDBC provided methods as otherwise the connection might be in an invalid state.

Comment: I am not sure why the session schema is set the way it is, but this is something which I am not allowed to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was a small syntax irregularity which I did not spot *because SQL developer executes it without problems...*

The following snippet works (note the parentheses after `immediate`):

```
SQL BEGIN
execute immediate('alter session set current_schema=user01');
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info('my client');
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module('my module', 'my action');
END;
```